# Enterprise Architect SynchTaggedValues not working

Tags: enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect `element.SynchTaggedValues()`is not working from an Add-in
but it works from the script inside EA.

Please find the code I used below.

Initially have creating an activity Element.

```
 EA.Element element = package.Elements.AddNew("Activity1", "Activity");
 element.Stereotype = "Activity";
 element.Update();
```

Later trying to synch TaggedValues for existing element.

```
element= repository.GetElementByGuid("{13D2915D-C249-4449-AA3C-8D807C54251C}");
bool ok = element.SynchTaggedValues("BPMN2.0", "Activity");
```

It returned false. No Sync is done here. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to just create the element correctly in the first place:

```
EA.Element element = package.Elements.AddNew("Activity1", "BPMN2.0::Activity");
```